# How to localize Angular's MatDialog

Tags: angular, localization, modal-dialog, angular-material

How do I localize a MatDialog?

Here my code:

```
//forgotpassword.component.ts

import { locale as english } from './i18n/en';
import { locale as italian } from './i18n/it';

@Component({
    selector   : 'forgot-password',
    templateUrl: './forgot-password.component.html',
})
export class ForgotPasswordComponent implements OnInit
{
    invalidCredentials: boolean = false;
    busy: boolean = false;

    constructor(
        private translationLoader: TranslationLoaderService,
        public dialog: MatDialog
    )
    {
        .
        .
        .
        this.translationLoader.loadTranslations(english, italian);
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
      .
      .
      .
    }


    onFormSubmit()
    {
        var email = this.forgotPasswordForm.get('email').value;

        .
        .
        .

        this.dialog.open(DialogContentUserDialog, {
            data: {
                email: email
            },
        });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector   : 'dialog-content-user-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'dialog-content-user-dialog.html'
})
export class DialogContentUserDialog
{
    constructor( @Inject( MAT_DIALOG_DATA ) public data: any )
    {
    }
}

// dialog-content-user-dialog.html

<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{FGTPWD.MODALTITLE | translate}}{{data.email}}</h2>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <p><span>&#10003;</span>{{FGTPWD.MODALSUBTITLE | translate}}</p>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Ok</button>
</div>
```

The use of pipes ( like `{{ID.SUBID | translate}}` ) is working fine in the parent html from which I open the dialog (forgot-password.component.html).

When I open the Dialog, on the contrary, I get this:  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_co.FGTPWD.MODALTITLE')

I guess I'd inject the the localization object, like the 'data' object, but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: What is `FGTPWD`?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Sorry, my stupid mistake!

I wrote '`{{ID.SUBID | translate}}`' instead of '`{{'ID.SUBID' | translate}}`'

Solved.